# how to create an image.php + imagebackground

Tags: php, image, background, imagecreatefrompng

I'm unable to combine these codes. I have tested but not working (error). Pls help me

***show ip***

```
 <?php
    $img_number = imagecreate(275,225);
    $backcolor = imagecolorallocate($img_number,102,102,153);
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img_number,205,205,205);
    imagefill($img_number,0,0,$backcolor);
    $number = " Your IP is $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
    Imagestring($img_number,10,5,5,$number,$textcolor);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($img_number);
    ?>
```

***+ background image***

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("imagetest.png");
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

in a file (image.php) /please help me /thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is replace the first 2 lines (except `<?php`) and fourth line in the first script with the first line in the second script.

In the first script, you are creating the image resource, creating a color resource and then filling the background. Instead, you want to create the image resource from an image and fill the background with that image.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $img = imagecreatefrompng("imagetest.png");
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img,205,205,205);
    $number = "Your IP is {$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]}"; //Also note the interpolation here. Not neccesary but it is nicer
    imagestring($img,10,5,5,$number,$textcolor);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

I have not tested this, however with having done similar things myself, I am confident that it will work. I would suggest however, that rather than hard coding the position of the text, you can compute the best place to put it based on the image's size. look at the [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.